# No me lee el objeto serializable que tengo en fichero binario en java

Tags: java

tengo un fichero binario el cual tiene contenido:
[image: Ejemplo del fichero binario que tengo, no puedo copiar y pegarlo asi que dejo foto]

Tengo una clase que pido que me lea una ruta introducida por el usuario, una ruta que sea un fichero .txt que tiene un objeto serializable de una clase que se llama Alumno:

```
package primeraevaluacion;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Alumno implements Comparable<Alumno> ,Serializable{
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3494335033678429772L;
    /**
     * 
     */
    
    int Nia;
    public String Nombre;
    String Apellidos;
    char Sexo;
    String Ciclo;
    String Curso;
    
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [Nia=" + Nia + " "+ "Nombre=" + Nombre + ", Apellidos=" + Apellidos + ", Sexo=" + Sexo + ", Ciclo="
                + Ciclo + ", Curso=" + Curso + ", Grupo=" + Grupo + "]";
    }

    String Grupo;

    public Alumno(int Nia, String Nombre, String Apellidos, char sexo, String Ciclo, String Curso,
            String Grupo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        this.Nia=Nia;
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.Apellidos=Apellidos;
        this.Sexo=sexo;
        this.Ciclo=Ciclo;
        this.Curso=Curso;
        this.Grupo=Grupo;
        
        
        
        
    }

    public Alumno() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Alumno o) {
        if (o.getNia() > Nia) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o.getNia()> Nia) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
        
    }
    
    

    public int getNia() {
        return Nia;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return Apellidos;
    }

    public char getSexo() {
        return Sexo;
    }

    public String getCiclo() {
        return Ciclo;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return Curso;
    }

    public String getGrupo() {
        return Grupo;
    }

    
}
```

Este es el main:

```
package primeraevaluacion;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class P04_tarea5leer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        String ruta;
        
        System.out.println("Introduzca la ruta del fichero donde están los alumnos \ny se mostraran por pantalla");
        
        ruta=Entrada.cadena();
        
        File f0 = new File(ruta);
        FileInputStream ficheroEntrada = new FileInputStream(f0);
        ObjectInputStream fichentrada = new ObjectInputStream(ficheroEntrada);
        
        try {
            while (fichentrada.available() > 0) {
                Alumno alumno = (Alumno) fichentrada.readObject();
                System.out.println("El Nia del alumno "+alumno.getNia()+" se llama "+alumno.getNombre());
                
            }
        } finally {
            // TODO: handle finally clause
        fichentrada.close();
        }
        
        
        
    }

}
```

Tengo una clase entrada (esta esta bien pero la dejo por si acaso)

```
package utilidades;
import java.io.*;

public class Entrada {
    static String inicializar() {
        String buzon = "";
        InputStreamReader flujo = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader teclado = new BufferedReader(flujo);
        try {
            buzon = teclado.readLine();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.append("Entrada incorrecta)");
        }
        return buzon;
    }

    public static int entero() {
        int valor = Integer.parseInt(inicializar());
        return valor;
    }
    
    public static int entero(String mensaje) {
        int n=0;
        boolean correcto;
        do {
            correcto=true;
            System.out.print(mensaje);
            try {
                n=entero();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("NÃºmero incorrecto. IntrodÃºzcalo de nuevo.");
                correcto=false;
            }
        }while(!correcto);
        return n;
    }

    public static double real() {
        double valor = Double.parseDouble(inicializar());
        return valor;
    }
    
    public static double real(String mensaje) {
        double n=0;
        boolean correcto;
        do {
            correcto=true;
            System.out.print(mensaje);
            try {
                n=real();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("NÃºmero incorrecto. IntrodÃºzcalo de nuevo.");
                correcto=false;
            }
        }while(!correcto);
        return n;
    }

    public static String cadena() {
        String valor = inicializar();
        return valor;
    }

    public static char caracter() {
        String valor = inicializar();
        return valor.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

La cosa es, por que cuando le meto la ruta correcta no entra en el while, he intentado buscar información en otras páginas web pero no llego a encontrar nada, y me da errores, este es el último sitio donde pregunto, un saludo

Comment: Es una mala práctica tener un try sin catch, es posible que una excepción esté saltado y no te estés dando cuenta

Comment: Me da errores, cuáles errores??

Comment: @Alfabravo El error es, que no me entra en el archivo de texto que quiero leer, y me salta un error del programa

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el error esta en la interpretación del método [available()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fileinputstream-available-method-in-java-with-examples/)

-El método `available()` de la clase `FileInputStream` se usa para devolver el número estimado de bytes restantes que se pueden leer desde el flujo de entrada **sin bloquear**. Este método devuelve el número de bytes que quedan por leer del archivo. sin embargo al tu querer leer un objeto guardado bloqueas el flujo ,el hecho de que devuelva 0 no significa que ya no haya nada que leer. Solo que la transmisión no puede garantizar que se pueda leer al menos un byte sin bloquearse.
[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662190/objectinputstream-available-method-doesnt-work-as-expected-java)

```
int ch=fichentrada.available() //ch devolvera 0 por tal motivo nunca entrara en el `while`
```

-como es 0 podrias declarar `while (entrada.available() > -1)` sin embargo
se producirá EOFException.

-otra manera de leer el .txt seria la siguiente,no se como guardas tus objetos asi que de producirse un EOFException podrias manejarlo con catch(lo mismo para la solucion anterior) ya que esta excepción indica:

> EOFException: si este flujo de entrada llega al final antes de leer ocho bytes.

```
try {
       ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f0));
       Object aux=entrada.readObject();//leer el primer objeto
       while (aux!=null) {//mientras haya objetos que leer
       Alumno alumno = (Alumno)aux;
       System.out.println("El Nia del alumno "+alumno.getNia()+" se llama "+alumno.getNombre());
                 aux=entrada.readObject();  
           }entrada.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("\nNo hay archivo");
        } 
        catch(EOFException e){
        System.out.println("\nSe llego al final del archivo");
        }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Hola buenas, he copiado tu codigo para ver si así me salía bien pero me sale un error: invalid stream header: 00084ACA


No me lee igualmente el fichero binario

¿Puede ser que mi objeto alumno tenga el serializable mal?

Comment: Vale, creo que era por el fichero binario, por que si no le pongo nada, da error, tengo que escribirle información